# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

Getting following error while running simple word count program using PyCharm.

Using- 
python 2.7
Hadoop 3.0.0
Macos High Sierra

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
    Setting default log level to "WARN".
    To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/usr/local/spark/jars/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    18/02/22 21:29:32 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/SAM/PycharmProjects/BB/BBTest.py", line 18, in <module>
        output = counts.collect()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 809, in collect
        port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
        answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
        format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
    : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:443)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:256)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2294)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2068)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:467)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

**Ignore following text **
plaintext plaintext plaintext plaintext plaintext plaintext plaintext plaintext plaintext plaintext plaintext plaintext  plaintext plaintext

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the source code you got the error on it's difficult to help you debug off the error alone. Is counts.collect() as used on line 18 (gleaned from error) supposed to have args? 
If that doesn't work My best guess given that you have Java errors in a python environment is that either your python or java installs are corrupted and need to be reinstalled.

Also, reading farther into your error, it appears hadoop is not stored where PyCharm knows where to look for it, based off " 18/02/22 21:29:32 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable"